# Vue cannot submit the form and return the error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I intend to submit the form and validate the content of the form.
but it always return
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

here is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <el-form :model="ruleForm" :rules="rules" ref="ruleForm" label-width="100px" class="demo-ruleForm">

      <el-form-item label="用户名" prop="user">
        <el-input type="text" v-model="ruleForm.user" auto-complete="off"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>

      <el-form-item>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('ruleForm')">提交</el-button>
      </el-form-item>

    </el-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      var validateUser = (rule, value, callback) => {
          if (value === '') {
            callback(new Error('请输入用户名'));
          }
          else {
              if (this.ruleForm.user !== '') {
                  this.$refs.ruleForm.validateField('user');
              }
          callback();
          }
      };
      return {
          ruleForm: {
              user: '',
           },
          rules: {
              user: [{validator: validateUser, trigger: 'blur'}],
          }
        };
    },
    methods: {
      submitForm(formName) {
          var vm = this
            this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
            if (valid) {
              submit()
            }
            else {
               return false
            }
         })
      },

      submit:function() {
          if (vm.ruleForm.user == 'admin' ) {
              console.log('succeed')
          }
           return true
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

the process of the code is very easy but it doesn't work and I have google that error may come from the recursive call of the function

```
 methods: {
      submitForm(formName) {
        var vm = this
        this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
          if (valid) {
            submit()
          }
          else {
            return false
          }
        })
      },
```

however, I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: Damn son, you managed to make Vue.js code unreadable.

Comment: That error means that you are stuck in an infinite loop somewhere. It may be a good idea to add some [debugger statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)  to check what's going on. Here's a JSFiddle to show you how debugger works: https://jsfiddle.net/4yant0m0/

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistakes - `this.$refs.ruleForm.validateField('user');` it shouldn't be validateField(**'user'**)  , that's why this part will be call infinitely and I replace this code with `callback()` so that it will return directly